# Evolution failed to send email using Google on gnome online accounts

Tags: 16.04, gnome, email, evolution

I have my Google account synced with gnome online accounts. Everything works fine from mail to files, until I try to send mail using evolution that sync'ed my gmail account. My inbox can be fetch from gmail, but when I try to send email I got this error : **"Welcome response error: Socket I/O timed out"**

any help would be appreciated, thanks

ubuntuGNOME 16.04

GNOME Shell 3.20.4

Comment: Seems like SMTP error, Which port are you using? Try using ports 25 or 465 or 587.

Comment: I believe it's a SMTP error because when I try to create mail account manually it works fine, but unfortunatelly email account created from gnome online accounts is not editable. I'd like to sync everything from calendar to cloud files using GOA but this one flaw really bothers me

Comment: Did you try using the ports I mentioned? Also, please go to Gmail's webmail, check the settings, as Google has introduced Two-Factor authentication, so, you may need to turn that off.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't edit the port nor the endpoint because I setup on Gnome Online Accounts and it just sync'ed with Evolution. Gnome already ask for authentication and it just sync'ed my calendar and things so I don't think that is not the issue. I bet the issue is Gnome Online Accounts put the wrong endpoint or the port for smtp.

Comment: Possible, in that case a viable alternative to Evolution is Thunderbird

Comment: hehe yeah Ialready tried Thunderbird and it's more stable and maintained, thanks anyway

Comment: Happy Ubuntu-ing.. :)

Comment: Same problem on Evolution 3.24.2. Google account added via GOA works all fine for everything (calendar, drive, syncing mails received) but can't send. Error reported is: > “HELO command failed: Peer failed to perform TLS handshake”. Also, the account properties for account via GOA does not have "send email" settings tab hence NO way to define server address, port and encryption type (hence above error) whereas this tab appears if added through Evolution Mail. Turned off 2-factor authentication in Google account settings

Comment: but still same error pops up thus it is clear that Evolution is missing "Send Email" settings for accounts added through GOA because same accounts work if I add it through Evolution Account Wizard and there all SMTP, encryption settings, etc appear. I believe Evolution simply misses server settings for accounts added via GOA (see the difference in two screenshots) If added via Evoluion:
https://ibb.co/cCO0ha If added via GOA:
https://ibb.co/hiuUav Same account, server settings for "send email" missing.

Answer (score 0):

I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` and now it works